# Check if an event.target is a child of an Angular directive (element)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, parent-child, element, dom-events

I made a custom (ul li) dropdown directive.

- When this dropdown is clicked the list is opened.
- When the list is clicked again the dropdown is closed.
- When an option in the list is clicked, the option is saved in a model an the dropdown will be closed.
- When clicking outside the dropdown the dropdown is closed.

Most of this is accomplished by the following code (Closing and opening part).

```
scope.closeDropDown = function () {
    scope.isOpened = false;
    $document.unbind('click');
};

//The part for opening and closing is pressed
scope.openDropDown = function () {
    if (scope.isOpened) {
        //The dropdown is already opened, close it
        scope.closeDropDown();
    } else {
        //Open the dropdown, and add an event handler to the document
        scope.isOpened = true;

        $document.bind('click', function (evt) {
            var target = $(evt.target);
            // Check if the document clicked element is a child of the directive
            // ATTENTION HERE
            if (!target.parents('dropdown').length) {
                //Target is not a child element, close the dropdown
                scope.closeDropDown();
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Look closely to the ATTENTION HERE part.
Here I set an event listener on the whole page. Using this gives me the following problem:

Example: When having multiple dropdowns (as example A and B).

- Open dropdown A

  - dropdown A opens correctly
- Open dropdown B

  - dropdown B opens correctly
  - dropdown A gets document event and says that the pressed element is a child of an dropdown directive (which is correct)
  - dropdown A does not closes (But I want it to close!)

***How do I check if the `event.target` is a child of the `angular.element` ?***
As now I'm only checking if the `event.target` is a child of a dropdown directive (this is only effective when using one dropdown directive)!

Comment: Please share updates on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by [Zia Ul Rehman Mughal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4738391/zia-ul-rehman-mughal) I'll update the question with an answer that I used in my own drop-down directive.

---

The part where I made the mistake was to add a click listener when the drop-down is opened, and remove it again when it is closed. **This is wrong**!

You have to add the listeners when the object is created, and remove them again when the object gets destroyed (with the angular `$destroy` event.

To check if the clicked target is a child of the element you can use the `length` attribute of `$element.find(event.target)`

```
function closeDropDown() {
    $scope.opened = false;
}

function handleClickEvent(event) {
    /* When the clicked element is not a child of the element and
       the dropdown is openend, close the dropdown. */
    if ($element.find(event.target).length === 0 && $scope.opened) {
        closeDropDown();
        /* Trigger new digest cycle */
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};

function setListeners() {
    /* Bind click event to the document, close the dropDown if clicked
       elsewhere on the page. */
    var clickHandler = handleClickEvent;
    $document.bind('click', clickHandler);

    /*  Remove the used event handlers when destroying the object */
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $document.unbind('click', clickHandler);
    });
}
```